# ScrollLeft scrolls to wrong location

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I'm making a Friday Quiz!
I want to use a scrollLeft-jQuery effect to go to the next question.
I have used this before without problem, however, now it keeps jumping round like mad.
What am I doing wrong?

The Site: www.carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/

The HTML:

```
                <div id="qWrap">
                    <ul id="qBox">
    <!--Q1-->           <li id="q1" class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion"><?php echo $Q1; ?>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#q2" class="<?php echo $Q1aClass; ?>"><h3><?php echo $Q1a; ?></h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q2" class="<?php echo $Q1bClass; ?>"><h3><?php echo $Q1b; ?></h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q2" class="<?php echo $Q1cClass; ?>"><h3><?php echo $Q1c; ?></h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
<!--Q2-->           <li id="q2" class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion"><?php echo $Q2; ?>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#q3" class="<?php echo $Q2aClass; ?>"><h3><?php echo $Q2a; ?></h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#q3" class="<?php echo $Q2bClass; ?>"><h3><?php echo $Q2b; ?></h3></a></li>

                            <li><a href="#q3" class="<?php echo $Q2cClass; ?>"><h3><?php echo $Q2c; ?></h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#qWrap{
width: 480px;
height: 260px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: scroll;
}

#qBox{
width: 1100%;
height: 260px;
display: block;
}


li.qContainer {
position: relative;
width: 9%!important;
height: 260px!important;
padding: 0px 0px;
margin: 0 50px 0 0px;
float: left;
}


.qQuestion {
width: 480px;
height: 50px;
padding: 10px 0px;
font-family: corbel;
font-size: 28px;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.qAnswers li a').bind('click',function(event){
                        var $anchor = $(this);
                        $('#qWrap').stop().animate({
                            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                        }, 2000);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated markup is bad.  View source in your console.  The pseudo markup is as follows:

```
<qwrap>
  <qbox>
    <li.qcontainer />
    <q2 />
    <li.qcontainer>
      <q3 />
    </li.qcontainer>
  </qbox>
</qwrap>
```

If you also run the following queries, you'll see why they scroll to different places.  Since the markup is off, the `offset` is calculating based on a different `offsetParent` for the the questions, thus why it inconsistently scrolls.

```
$('#q2').offsetParent();
$('#q3').offsetParent();
```

Fix your markup, and your scrolling problem goes away.

EDIT: once your markup is correct, then you can calculate how far to scroll `qWrap` by checking the `position` attribute.  `offset` is relative to the document, whereas `position` will report the offset relative to the parent.  See http://api.jquery.com/position/

Add `position: relative` to the qBox.  This will make `position` relative to the box being scrolled for the questions.

Then your code is pretty much what you already had, except changing `offset` to `position`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.qAnswers li a').bind('click',function(event){
                        var $anchor = $(this);
                        $('#qWrap').stop().animate({
                            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).position().left
                        }, 2000);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
 });
```

Comment: I tried to fix the markup (see edit) and it still doesn't work. or did I misinterpret your answer?

Comment: @CarlPapworth See edits.  Now that your markup is correct I could make further observations about your Question.

Comment: Thanks a million! Your help has been godly!

Answer (score 0):

in your .stop(), put

```
.stop(true, true).animate
```

see if that helps you.